# Wait for completion of a calculation without UI freeze

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to implement a search function in an Android app that takes text from an `AutoCompleteTextView`, waits if there hasn't been made a change in the last 1.5 seconds and shows the search results. For this I use the `TextWatcher` class.

However, all my tries to implement this behavior ran into trouble with some functions only being allowed in the UI thread itself (via `runOnUIThread`) or the thread having `Looper.prepare()` called before.

In all attempts, the app crashes randomly when entering additional characters or deleting some, does not show any search results or reload to the start activity.

The following is a simplyfied recreation of my most recent try, where I use a `Handler`.

`search.getResults` is the long computation and `matches` is an array that has to be filled *before* `delayableAdapterCreation` creates the `ArrayAdapterWithSpaceFilter`.

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    public final static int MAX_NUMBER_OF_SUGGESTIONS = 4; // only show a max of 4 suggestions if more were found
    public final static int SEARCH_CHAR_AMOUNT = 3; // only search if at least 3 characters were typed
    public final static long SEARCH_DELAY_MILLIS = (long) 1500; // the time to wait for no text changes in milliseconds
    private Search search;
    private AutoCompleteTextView textView;
    private String[] matches;
    private String userStartRequest;
    private Entry[] suggestions;
    private FragmentListenter sListener;
    private EntryFunctions ef = new EntryFunctions();
    private Runnable delayableSearch;
    private Runnable delayableAdapterCreation;
    private Handler delayableSearchHandler;    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        delayableSearchHandler = new Handler();

        delayableSearch = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                userStartRequest = textView.getText().toString();
                sListener.onFragmentFinish(userStartRequest);
                suggestions = search.getResults(userStartRequest);
                matches = ef.fillMatches(suggestions);
            }
        };

        delayableAdapterCreation = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ArrayAdapterWithSpaceFilter<String> adapter =
                        new ArrayAdapterWithSpaceFilter<String>(getActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                matches);
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        };

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        textViewHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (!(context instanceof FragmentListenter)) throw new AssertionError();
        sListener = (FragmentListenter) context;
    }

    /**
     * Interface for communicate to activity
     */
    public interface FragmentListenter {
        void onFragmentFinish(String userStartRequest);
    }


    /**
     * Handler for the AutoCompleteTextView
     */
    private void textViewHandler() {
        try {
            textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById
                    (R.id.startNaviAutoCompleteTextView);
            search = new Search();
            System.out.println("Created Search object");

            textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    System.out.println("TextWatcher beforeTextChanged");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, final int start, int before, int count) {
                    delayableSearchHandler.removeCallbacks(delayableSearch);                        userStartRequest = textView.getText().toString();
                    sListener.onFragmentFinish(userStartRequest);
                    if (textView.getText().length() >=
                            SEARCH_CHAR_AMOUNT) {
                        new Thread(delayableSearch).start();
                        delayableSearchHandler.postDelayed
                            (delayableAdapterCreation, SEARCH_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, it does not matter to me, whether the calculation already starts whenever a new character is typed into the `AutoCompleteTextView` and an eventual old search is canceled or the search starts after the 1.5 seconds.

The above code does crash if the search term yields no results and there are problems with the results list. Sometimes it shows up for what has been entered a few keystrokes ago (so if I search for abcd slowly I get search results for abc), sometimes it doesn't show up at all. My guess would be a race condition or some problem with calling the `textViewHandler` or `onTextChanged` methods multiple times, even though `delayableSearchHandler.removeCallbacks(delayableSearch)` should prevent this from happening.

Can anyone explain, what the interaction between the worker thread and the UI thread would have to look like, so it is guaranteed that the search delivers it's results?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Any long running operation (Network call, database search...) can take long time to execute thus blocking the UI. Prior to Ice cream sandwich this kind of behavior was tolerated by the android runtime.

[This article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) might be a good read

Comment: I'm very sorry, I made that sound misunderstandable in the question. The current state of the code does not crash (that only happened in a lot of prior tries). This one just does not show any search results immediately, but shows them when i let the computation run for the delayed time and then add another letter to it or remove one. I thought the exact error would be irrelevant, since it should be self-fixing once the communication and calls between the UI and worker threads works.

Comment: I don't think I follow. Does your code produce any undesired outcome? or does it crash under any specific circumstances ?

Comment: The desired outcome is that after 1.5 seconds (or longer if the search itself takes longer) a list of possible matches is shown on the UI. In this shown code, the list feels like showing up randomly. Sometimes it shows up for what has been entered a few keystrokes ago (so if I search for abcd slowly I get search results for abc), sometimes it doesn't show up at all. In the very first implementation of the search bar we just did the calculation after every added character, freezing the UI, show the results when finished and then letting the user type another letter. This was too slow.

Comment: It does crash, my bad. Gonna add a lot to the original question.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to realize the intended behavior within my given time frame, so we swapped to a solution of only searching once the user hits return and only search one time instead of after every typed character. However, I will return to this problem once I got more time because it sounds interesting to me.